# How to remove black diamond question mark in c# file stream

Tags: c#, winforms, text-files, filestream

How can I remove the black diamond question mark when I read a text file?

In the text file the real character is • but after reading the text file it became �. I don't know how to manipulate/delete that character.

Comment: Can you show us how you are reading this file? @MMakati

Answer (score 4):

This character means, that you are reading the file in the wrong encoding. At first you need to know how your file is encoded. You could get this informatio from Notepad++ for example. Then in your code read the file with this encoding specified. Here is an example to read unicode files:

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.Unicode);
```

Remove character:

```
text.Replace("•", string.Empty);
```

Comment: but how are you going to remove that character?

Comment: Do you wan to remove the original character?

Answer (score 2):

You could just set a conditional for that character.  Then use the Remove method.  something like this:

```
if(inputstring.StartsWith('�')
{
    inputstring = inputstring.Remove(0,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [black diamond with a question mark is a place-holder for unrecognized characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29). You can use Regex to replace `•` with an empty string:

```
//...
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
//...

string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "file.txt");

string yourString = Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(filePath, "file.txt")), @"\u2022", "");
```

Since the `•` character's value is `u2022`, the Regex pattern will match it and replace that with an empty string. `Regex.Replace()` takes 3 arguments in this case: the source string, the expression, and the string to replace the text that matchs the pattern.

I tested it out and it worked just fine:

**Contents of file.txt: `hello, •world!`**

***After using Regex to replace `•`:***

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

```
File.ReadAllLines(pathTxt, Encoding.GetEncoding(28591));
```